# Node.js - Heroku server crashes when this code runs

Tags: node.js, heroku, crash

I have a Node.js application that runs perfectly on my localhost.

However, when i uploaded to Heroku, the server crashes once a portion of the code is executed.

The given code is supposed to extract a portion from a URL string that was passed from a form.

This is the code that causes the server to crash:

```
  function getUserDetails(username) {
    return new Promise(done => {
        var data = [];
        https.get(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`, resp => {
            resp.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk));
            resp.on('end', () => {
                var json = JSON.parse(data.join(''));
                done(json.graphql.user);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

After Heroku crashedd - and it stil crashes consistently, i checked the logs with `heroku logs --tail`.

This is the report from the logs:

```
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782839+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined:1
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782863+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782865+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782867+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782870+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON
 input
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782872+00:00 app[web.1]: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782874+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.resp.on (/app/ap
p/routes.js:108:33)
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782876+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:
203:15)
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782878+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.
js:1145:12)
2019-10-06T10:59:40.782880+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/
process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2019-10-06T10:59:40.869547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2019-10-06T10:59:40.847583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-06T10:59:40.790256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connect
ion closed without response" method=POST path="/MY_PATH" host=MY_HOST.herok
uapp.com request_id=15118004-c799-45bd-a0a9-909cbd3a5e86 fwd="130.43.125.250" dy
no=web.1 connect=1ms service=101ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the url value from?
Looks like you are reading in some other place from a json input and thats incorrectly formatted or missing a tag or so.

On running your piece of code locally it works as expected.

```
var URL = require('url').URL;

url = "stackoverflow.com/questions/58256767/node-js-heroku-server-crashes-when this-code-runs";

if(!/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)){
  url = "http://" + url;}
let parsed = new URL(url);
let retrieved = parsed.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

Output :

```
node v10.16.0

=> 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256767/node-js-heroku-server-crashes-when-this-code-runs'
```

Comment: I edited the question. The code that caused it to crash was wrong. I inserted the new code. The crash happens at JSON.parse() - as evident by the error message.